# Save object in Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

Let's say i have class which looks like this :

```
class A { 
   var property1:Int
   var property2:String

   init(property1: Int, property2: String) {
      self.property1 = property1
      self.property2 = property2   
   }
}
```

(...)

```
let a = A(property1: 10, property2: "Smth")
```

Is it the way to save that object in `CoreData` ? Do i have to create via NSManageObject Subclass new class with this name and then do everything from the beginning ? Or there is a way to convert class to match it without changes ? Btw. via this generator in the latest update is a bug which says that those class is ambiguous :o

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Core Data classes (entities) must be `NSManagedObject`. The generator is not a bug, it's most likely a wrong user setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do need to have an `NSManagedObject` or a subclass, but you can't have two classes with the same name. With Core Data you normally define an entity type in the Core Data model editor, and then create a subclass to match that entity (Xcode usually creates the subclass automatically these days).

It's very unusual to have a second non-managed class that mirrors the Core Data object. You can use an `NSManagedObject` subclass on its own. You can still have `property1` and `property2`, but your initializer will have to change. For managed objects you must have a managed objet context at initialization, which generally means including one as an argument to the initializer.

You might find it worthwhile to take a look at Apple's [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html?utm_source=iosstash.io).